# InkCanvas Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, crystal-reports, inkcanvas

I have a WPF/MVVM application on .net framework 4.0 using crystal reports 13. On one of the windows, i am using an inkcanvas control to capture signatures. I need to save this in sql server and show on crystal reports.

What is the best way of doing this? I can only save strokecollection and show it back on the inkcanvas but i need to also reproduce the signature on crystal reports. So far, i have tried converting strokes to bmp but it's coming dark on the report.

Is there another control i can try?